# How can I print all the settings in Test configuration for a project build using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I have a scala-js project, adding a particular library dependency, is affecting the way project test cases are running. Without the library dependency everything's fine, the moment I add them, tests doesn't execute. I want to check all sbt settings, if those are getting affected. Is there any way I can print all settings and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BuildStructure.data`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/api/sbt/internal/BuildStructure.html#data:sbt.internal.util.Settings[sbt.Scope]) seems to give access to all the settings by scope. We could access it by defining a [custom command](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Commands.html#Defining+a+Command) `printAllTestSettings` like so:

```
def printAllTestSettings = Command.command("printAllTestSettings") { state =>
  val structure = Project.extract(state).structure

  val testScope =
    Scope(
      Select(ProjectRef(new File("/home/mario/sandbox/hello-world-scala/"), "root")),
      Select(ConfigKey("test")),
      Zero,
      Zero
    )

  structure
    .data
    .keys(testScope)
    .foreach(key => println(s"${key.label} = ${structure.data.get(testScope, key).get}"))

 state
}

commands ++= Seq(printAllTestSettings)
```

Here is output snippet:

```
...
managedSourceDirectories = List(/home/mario/sandbox/hello-world-scala/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/test)
managedResourceDirectories = List(/home/mario/sandbox/hello-world-scala/target/scala-2.12/resource_managed/test)
testLoader = Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/home/mario/sandbox/hello-world-scala/,root)), Select(ConfigKey(test)), Zero, Zero),testLoader)))
packageBin = Task((taskDefinitionKey: ScopedKey(Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/home/mario/sandbox/hello-world-scala/,root)), Select(ConfigKey(test)), Zero, Zero),packageBin)))
...
```